# Exchange Powershell Script Advice

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I need to apply for the following to Multiple E-mail addresses/DL lists could anyone assist

```
$endDate = Get-Date
$startDate = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-6)

$sent = Get-MessageTrackingLog -resultsize unlimited -eventid send -Start $startDate -End $endDate -Sender "distgroup@domainname.com"


$received = Get-MessageTrackingLog -resultsize unlimited -eventid receive -Start $startDate -End $endDate -Recipients "distgroup@domainnme.com"

$results = $send + $receive
$results | Export-Csv -Path "filepath" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What exactly is your question? If you want to apply an action to multiple elements you use a loop. ‍♂️